# Miniconda, tenser flow , Nvidia cuDNN

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, gpu

I get these errors in pycharm python 3.9 when trying to run on gpu. I put those directories paths from MC:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.5\bin (and cuDNN version 8.3 )in the PATH from Environment Variables but the error says they are not found. Any ideea? I dont know how to ask better so excuses in advance but I am just trying to use this for a CNN model.

> 2023-04-04 19:45:48.825858: W
> tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could
> not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll
> not found 2023-04-04 19:45:48.826122: I
> tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart
> dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
> WARNING:tensorflow:From
> C:\Users\renat\PycharmProjects\IA\Proiect\main.py:12: is_gpu_available
> (from tensorflow.python.framework.test_util) is deprecated and will be
> removed in a future version. Instructions for updating: Use
> `tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')` instead. 2023-04-04
> 19:45:50.638428: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193]
> This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network
> Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in
> performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2 To enable them in other
> operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
> 2023-04-04 19:45:50.657795: W
> tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could
> not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll
> not found 2023-04-04 19:45:50.658910: W
> tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could
> not load dynamic library 'cublas64_11.dll'; dlerror: cublas64_11.dll
> not found 2023-04-04 19:45:50.659993: W
> tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could
> not load dynamic library 'cublasLt64_11.dll'; dlerror:
> cublasLt64_11.dll not found 2023-04-04 19:45:50.661295: W
> tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could
> not load dynamic library 'cufft64_10.dll'; dlerror: cufft64_10.dll not
> found 2023-04-04 19:45:50.662502: W
> tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could
> not load dynamic library 'curand64_10.dll'; dlerror: curand64_10.dll
> not found 2023-04-04 19:45:50.663589: W
> tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could
> not load dynamic library 'cusolver64_11.dll'; dlerror:
> cusolver64_11.dll not found 2023-04-04 19:45:50.664677: W
> tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could
> not load dynamic library 'cusparse64_11.dll'; dlerror:
> cusparse64_11.dll not found 2023-04-04 19:45:50.666352: W
> tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could
> not load dynamic library 'cudnn64_8.dll'; dlerror: cudnn64_8.dll not
> found

Answer (score 0):

```js
const tensorflowButton = document.getElementById('run-tensorflow-button');
const tensorflowOutput = document.getElementById('tensorflow-output');

tensorflowButton.addEventListener('click', async () => {
  tensorflowOutput.value = 'TensorFlow version: 2.12.0\n';
  tensorflowOutput.value += 'CUDA support: False\n';
  tensorflowOutput.value += 'GPU support: False\n';
  tensorflowOutput.value += 'xla support: True\n';
  tensorflowOutput.value += 'RCOM support: False\n';
  tensorflowOutput.value += 'GPU devices available: []\n';
});

const pytorchButton = document.getElementById('run-pytorch-button');
const pytorchOutput = document.getElementById('pytorch-output');

pytorchButton.addEventListener('click', async () => {
  pytorchOutput.value = 'PyTorch version: 2.0.0+cu118\n';
  pytorchOutput.value += 'CUDA support: True\n';
  pytorchOutput.value += 'GPU devices available: 1\n';
  pytorchOutput.value += 'Current GPU device: 0\n';
});
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    color: #333;
}

.container {
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}

h1 {
    font-size: 28px;
    margin-top: 0;
}

pre {
    background-color: #000;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    overflow-x: auto;
  color: #fff
}

code {
    font-family: monospace;
}

button {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-size: 18px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

textarea {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
#terminal-section {
  background-color: #2e2e2e;
  color: #444;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.terminal {
  background-color: #1e1e1e;
  border: none;
  color: #f8f8f2;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  resize: none;
  width: 100%;
}

.terminal-input-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.prompt {
  color: #50fa7b;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.terminal-input {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  color: #f8f8f2;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 16px;
  outline: none;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Stack Overflow answer : Miniconda, tenser flow, Nvidia cuDNN</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Problem of recognition of my graphic card with Tensor Flow</h1>
        <p>I have the same problem as you, but I followed the whole procedure of <a href="https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu?hl=fr" title="TensoFlow install"> TensorFlow</a>, as well as the one of <a href="https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Windows&target_arch=x86_64&target_version=10&target_type=exe_local " title="CUDA toolkit">Cuda Toolkit</a> and finally <a href="https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/cudnn/install-guide/index.html#installwindows" title="cuDNN">cuDNN</a>.</p>
<section id="tensorflow-section">
<h2>Avec TensorFlow</h2>
   <pre><code class="language-python">
import tensorflow as tf

print("TensorFlow version:", tf.__version__)
print("CUDA support:", tf.test.is_built_with_cuda())
print("GPU support:", tf.test.is_built_with_gpu_support())
print("xla support:", tf.test.is_built_with_xla())
print("RCOM support:", tf.test.is_built_with_rocm())
print("GPU devices available:", tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))
            </code></pre>
      <button id="run-tensorflow-button">Run TensorFlow</button>
            <textarea id="tensorflow-output" rows="6" cols="50" readonly></textarea>
        </div>
    </section>
<div class="container">
    <section id="pytorch-section">
            <h2>Avec PyTorch</h2>
      <p>Alors que l'utilisation de PyTorch avec la même procédure pour Cuda fonctionne très bien :</p>
            <pre><code class="language-python">
import torch

print("PyTorch version:", torch.__version__)
print("CUDA support:", torch.cuda.is_available())
print("GPU devices available:", torch.cuda.device_count())
print("Current GPU device:", torch.cuda.current_device())
            </code></pre>
            <button id="run-pytorch-button">Run PyTorch</button>
            <textarea id="pytorch-output" rows="6" cols="50" readonly></textarea>
    </div>
    </section>
<section id="terminal-section">
  <div class="container">
  <p>And obviously the instatlllation of Tensorflow-gpu is impossible due to an error in the code it seems:</p>

    <h2>Terminal</h2>
    <textarea id="terminal" class="terminal" rows="10" cols="50" readonly>
(venv) A:\....\pip install tensorflow-gpu                    
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -rotobuf (a:\...\venv\lib\site-packages)
WARNING: Ignoring invalid distribution -rotobuf (a:\...\venv\lib\site-packages)
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://pypi.ngc.nvidia.com
Collecting tensorflow-gpu
  Downloading tensorflow-gpu-2.12.0.tar.gz (2.6 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [41 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "A:\...\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_vendor\packaging\requirements.py", line 35, in __init__
          parsed = parse_requirement(requirement_string)
        File "A:\...\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_vendor\packaging\_parser.py", line 64, in parse_requirement      
          return _parse_requirement(Tokenizer(source, rules=DEFAULT_RULES))
        File "A:\...\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_vendor\packaging\_parser.py", line 82, in _parse_requirement     
          url, specifier, marker = _parse_requirement_details(tokenizer)
        File "A:\...\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_vendor\packaging\_parser.py", line 126, in _parse_requirement_det
ails
          marker = _parse_requirement_marker(
        File "A:\...\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_vendor\packaging\_parser.py", line 147, in _parse_requirement_mar
ker
          tokenizer.raise_syntax_error(
        File "A:\a...\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_vendor\packaging\_tokenizer.py", line 163, in raise_syntax_error 
          raise ParserSyntaxError(
      setuptools.extern.packaging._tokenizer.ParserSyntaxError: Expected end or semicolon (after name and no valid version specifier)
          python_version>"3.7"
                        ^
     
      The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
     
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\...\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4vsp1tpg\tensorflow-gpu_66cf6632549a48978e05ca559643cab6\setup.py", line 40, in <module>
          setuptools.setup()
        File "A:\...\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 107, in setup
          _install_setup_requires(attrs)
        File "A:\...\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 78, in _install_setup_requires
          dist.parse_config_files(ignore_option_errors=True)
        File "A:\...\venv\lib\site-packages\_virtualenv.py", line 21, in parse_config_files
          result = old_parse_config_files(self, *args, **kwargs)
        File "A:\...\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 887, in parse_config_files
          self._finalize_requires()
        File "A:\...\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 594, in _finalize_requires
          self._move_install_requirements_markers()
        File "A:\...\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 634, in _move_install_requirements_markers
          inst_reqs = list(_reqs.parse(spec_inst_reqs))
        File "A:\...\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_vendor\packaging\requirements.py", line 37, in __init__
          raise InvalidRequirement(str(e)) from e
      setuptools.extern.packaging.requirements.InvalidRequirement: Expected end or semicolon (after name and no valid version specifier)
          python_version>"3.7"
                        ^
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

    </textarea>
    <div class="terminal-input-container">
      <span class="prompt"></span>
      <input type="text" id="terminal-input" class="terminal-input" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section>
<footer>
  <div class="container">
    <p class="conclusion">Unless I'm mistaken, and if I missed something, the problem would come from the version of TensorFlow that doesn't support CUDA versions (for me Pascal 6.1). For more information about CUDA and its versions, see <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA" target="_blank">https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA</a>.</p>
  </div>
</footer>
</section>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pyodide/0.18.1/full/pyodide.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: sorry I thought I was making a nice presentation but it looks like this (with more details and some commands)... you'll have to 'run code snippet' the snippet and switch to a 'full page'

Comment: This isn't an answer by the looks of it. If you have a different question, please post a new question entirely in English. If it is, please make that more clear, and it still has to all be in English.